# Converges in inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Assume $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal/orthogonal system in an (complex) inner product space. Does $$\sum_{i\in I}\langle f_i,f\rangle f_i$$ always converges for any $f$ (may not to $f$)? Especially, when $I$ is uncountable.

And we define convergency of a sum $\sum_I x_i$ on an arbitrary set by: if there exists $g$ and for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a finite set $F$ and for all other finite set $H\supseteq F,|g-\sum_H x_i|<\epsilon$ as an analogue to the limit of series in analysis.

Comment: I believe it only converges to $f$ if the orthonormal system is "complete". That is, the span of $f_i$ is dense in your vector space.

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah Completeness does not imply anything. When the space is Hilbert then completeness is enough and sufficient. But I just want to know for any arbitrary system whether this sum converges to something.

Comment: Ah yeah. I implicitly read your problem as in a hilbert space, given the tag.

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah Well, yes it is on the way there, as preparation knowledge. Maybe I should remove the tag.

Comment: Bessel's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Completeness is necessary. Otherwise the series converges in the completion, not necessarily in $X$. [For a counterexample you can take any element in the completion of an inner product space that does not belong to the original space and look at its expansion with respect to an orthonormal basis].

Now  assume that $X$ is a Hilbert space.

Hints for proof of convergence: for any finite subcollection $\{g_1,g_2,..,g_n\}$ of $\{f_i\}$ we have $\|f-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \langle f, g_k\rangle g_k\|^{2} \geq 0 $. Expanding this we get $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |\langle f, g_k\rangle |^{2} \leq \|f\|^{2}$. This implies that $\{i: \langle f, f_i\rangle \neq 0\}$ is at most countable. If this set is $i_1,i_2,...$ then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \langle f, f_{i_k}\rangle f_{i_k}$ converges because its partial sums are Cauchy. Now verify that the required uncountable sum exists and equals $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \langle f, f_{i_k}\rangle f_{i_k}$.

Comment: The OP requires a series involving $f \in X$. So I don't think your counter-example of the first paragraph works because you require $f \notin X$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you let $X$ be the set of sequences $x_n \in \ell^2$ such that for some constant $C$, $x_n = C/n$ for all but finitely many $n$; and the orthonormal system is $\{ e_{2n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}^+ \}$.  Then for $f = (\frac{1}{n})_{n=1}^\infty \in X$, the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle f, e_{2n} \rangle e_{2n}$ would have to be $g$ where $g_n = \frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is even or $g_n = 0$ if $n$ is odd; but that is not an element of $X$.

Comment: What is your $X$? Is it a space only finitely many terms are $C/n$ all others are zero? Something like $(2/1,2/2,2/3,0,2/5,0,0,2/8,0,0,...)$?

Comment: No, it's the one where all but finitely many terms are $C/n$.  Another way to say it would be that $n x_n$ is eventually constant.  An example of an element would be $(0, 3, 2, \pi, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{3}{6}, \frac{3}{7}, \frac{3}{8}, \ldots)$.